# jquery addClass child selector failed

Tags: jquery, css

i use this css

```
fa-info {
  background-color: green;
  font-size: 30px;
}
fa-info .active {
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

with this markup

```
 <fa-info>test</fa-info>
```

and this jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('fa-info').bind('mouseover', function(){
       $(this).addClass('active');
    });
    $('fa-info').bind('mouseout', function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

dont work

if i change the css code to

```
fa-info {
  background-color: green;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.active {
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

this works why?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you specify a selector like this:

```
fa-info .active
```

You are asking for a child of `fa-info` that has the `.active` class.  That is not the situation you have.

To have the active class on the `fa-info` object itself, your CSS rule would need to be this:

```
fa-info.active {
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

With no space between `fa-info` and `.active`.  That indicates you want them on the same object.

To summarize:

```
/* CSS rule that targets a child of fa-info with the active class */
fa-info .active {
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
}

/* CSS rule that targets a fa-info with the active class on the same object */
fa-info.active {
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

Comment: great works, but sass compile the css file with fa-info .active

Comment: @MartinSchäpker - then you are probably using the wrong sass syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If should be

```
fa-info.active
```

No space. This is 'give me a fa-info tag with the class `active`'

`fa-info .active`, with a space, means 'give me anything with a `active` class inside of a fa-info tag'

Answer (score 0):

With the selector:

```
fa-info .active
```

you are searching a descendant of a `fa-info` element with the class `.active`

If you want to point an element with both the attributes remove the space between them, like:

```
fa-info.active
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8U3rG/

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors

> For example, the selector .key selects all elements that have the
>   class name key. The selector p.key selects only `<p>` elements that
>   have the class name key.